# URL Vulnerabilities

Tags: security, url, google-docs, server-side-attacks

I'm researching URLs that I'm building against the unique URL that google docs create once you select and send a URL to anyone.

My URL looks like: `https://example.com/?doc=abcd123)`

- Should I encode the variable doc in base64? Should it betoken alike
- wherewith the id and a key that the other end needs to decrypt?
- Whatis The security issue we are vulnerable to?
- How exactly can an attacker exploit this vulnerability?
- What do we need to do to fix the vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of this potential vulnerability is *insecure direct object references*. Potential, because it is not possible to see out of the example you have provided if you are affected. Let me put an example here.

If you allow for unauthenticated `doc=myexcel.xls` then this is an insecure direct object reference and you are affected. Someone will come and try to fuzz doc into getting `doc=sensitive.xls`.

If you allow for authenticated and authorized `doc=myexcel.xls` then this is a secure direct object reference and this would be ok too.

If you allow for unauthenticated `doc=efa64d43-cca2-444c-9bcf-9f78b114bda4` where `efa64d43-cca2-444c-9bcf-9f78b114bda4` is a UUID type 4 containing 128 bits of entropy pointing to a file you wish to download, then this is insecure indirect object reference and this would be ok.

You can read more about potential prevention in [OWASP Cheat Sheets](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).